# CSS for position absolute div showing over scrolling container

Tags: html, css

For this issue there are two containers on the page. Each is set to overflow:auto.

In the upper container (green) we have a series of buttons. Each button toggles the display of a popup (blue). This blue container needs to display on top of the lower container (red) regardless of the scroll position of the upper container.

We get part of the way there by setting the popup to position:absolute as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

However, when we scroll down further and try to click on a button which was previously hidden it isn't positioned under the button correctly.

[image]

I would like a solution which doesn't require Javascript calculation on button press. I also don't want to use position fixed since I want the popup to remain under the button even on page resize.

Here is the code to reproduce this issue.

```js
  function togglePopup(index) {
    var element = document.getElementById('popup'+index);

    if (element.style.display === 'none') {
      element.style.display = '';
    } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

```css
  .outerWrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
  }

  .upper {
    height: 30%;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  .lower {
    height: 70%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .row {
    height: 70px;
  }

  .popup {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outerWrapper">

  <div class="upper">
    <div class="row">
      <button onclick="togglePopup(1)">test</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup1" style="display:none">
        popup content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button onclick="togglePopup(2)">test</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup2" style="display:none">
        popup content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button onclick="togglePopup(3)">test</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup3" style="display:none">
        popup content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower">


  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach using vanilla javascript:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var popups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');

function togglePopup() {

    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(buttons,this);

    var popup = popups.item(index);
    getComputedStyle(popup,null).display === 'none' ? popup.style.display = 'block' : popup.style.display = 'none';

 for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
  if (i === index) {continue;}
        var popup = popups[i];
        popup.style.display = 'none';
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click',togglePopup,false);
}
```

```css
.box, .box button {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.box {
width: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}

.top {
height: 120px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,191,0);
}

.bottom {
height: 280px;
border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}

.box button {
margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.popup {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,255);
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box top">
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
</div>

<div class="box bottom">
<div class="popup">popup 1 content</div>
<div class="popup">popup 2 content</div>
<div class="popup">popup 3 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run this code I see the popup appear in the top left corner of the red box. I am trying to get it to appear just below the button pressed. This is really intended to be similar to a dropdown.